# Pandas ignores set encoding in read_csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, parsing

Using Linux, Pandas 1.0.1 and Python 3.6 I get a strange error in production:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 199, in run
    new_deps = self._run_get_new_deps()
  File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 141, in _run_get_new_deps
    task_gen = self.task.run()
  File "/opt/app-root/src/import_validation/validate_csv.py", line 275, in run
    validate(temp_csv, self.query_id)
  File "/opt/app-root/src/import_validation/validate_csv.py", line 263, in validate
    pandas.read_csv(path, encoding='latin1', sep=sep)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 454, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1133, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/opt/app-root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 2037, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 859, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 874, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 951, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1083, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1136, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1253, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1268, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1458, in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 12: invalid continuation byte
```

As you can see in the traceback, I am already setting the encoding to latin1:

```
pandas.read_csv(path, encoding='latin1', sep=sep)
```

Why does pandas try to decode UTF-8 when i have specified latin1 as encoding? I have tried to use other aliases for latin1, it gives the same result.

Any idea why pandas seems to be ignoring my encoding setting?

Edit: Removed comment on not working in Windows. The same error happened, I just cheated when I passed the file, not passing it the same way.

Comment: Sound weird... Could you build a minimal csv file exhibiting the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a few too many layers of abstraction. I had a wrapper around this that tried to decompress the file if it ended with 'gz'. I then gave pandas not a path, but a temporary file. This file does of course already have its encoding set, and then the encoding setting is ignored in pandas. The solution is/was to pass the encoding to the temporary file, or as I did, just pass the original path to pandas, as it handles decompressed of files automatically.